# b43 + AMD on LTS 18.04 not working

Tags: drivers, broadcom

I have an old (how could it be otherwise) HP elitebook 745 with an AMD processor and a broadcom wifi. The driver was not present until running

```
apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

but apparently loads now. this step was also listed in the referenced "installing broadcom drivers article".

A new problem appears, visible from dmesg

```
[    1.591898] bcma: bus0: Found chip with id 43228, rev 0x00 and package 0x08
[    1.591923] bcma: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x25, class 0x0)
[    1.591942] bcma: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x1E, class 0x0)
[    1.592049] bcma: bus0: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x12, class 0x0)
[    1.592068] bcma: bus0: Core 3 found: SDIO Device (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x829, rev 0x07, class 0x0)
[    1.604210] bcma: bus0: Bus registered

[    5.164775] b43 bcma0:1 wlp2s0b1: renamed from wlan0
[    5.188343] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0b1: link is not ready
[    5.348195] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[    5.468139] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    5.512831] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0b1: link is not ready
[    5.563673] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0b1: link is not ready
[    5.620189] AMD-Vi: Event logged [
[    5.620196] INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST device=00:00.1 address=0x000000fdf80c0020 flags=0x0a00]
```

The symptom is that now "WiFi networks" is shown as an option in the "Network" menu, but is grayed out (no actual WLAN networks are shown). If I try to connect to a wlan as hidden network it fails, and dmesg shows the last lines of the above script again.

ifconfig yields

```
wlp2s0b1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether ac:e0:10:my:ma:ca  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

following a comment I also issued below command:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:05e2]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I then removed `firmware-b43-installer` and used `apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`. Further I uncommented in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
# replaced by b43 and ssb.
# blacklist bcm43xx
```

Then we still have the bcma as a kernel module ...

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:05e2]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

After removing the comment in `blacklist.conf` and checking rfkill the situation is as before, the wifi seems to be known to the system, but is not operational, is grayed out and does not see networks.

I am checking:

```
iw wlo1 info
Interface wlo1
    ifindex 3
    wdev 0x1
    addr ac:e0:10:3d:f2:f4
    type managed
    wiphy 0
    txpower 200.00 dBm
```

so in principle it should be fine. However in dmesg I see sometimes: `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready`. (Bluetooth firmware load fails now, but I suppose that does not matter).

Could this be a networking issue?
What could be missing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I think the question has not been answered in the earlier article

Comment: Why do you think it? You installed a wrong driver. Install `bcmwl-kernel-source` and the job is done.

Comment: I also tried the `bcmwl-kernel-source` and still have the same symptom. I suspect the key is the last error message in the dmesg log: `
[  196.986901] wlo1: Broadcom BCM4359 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)`

[  197.028788] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[  197.156458] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[  197.158588] AMD-Vi: Event logged [
[  197.158595] INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST device=00:00.1 address=0x000000fdf80c0020 flags=0x0a00]`

Comment: Please install `bcmwl-kernel-source` and post output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`. Most likely Secure Boot is on. The key is that `bcma` is a wrong driver for this device.

Comment: thanks for the note. I installed `bcmwl-kernel-source` (after having purged everything broadcom related beforehand, including the `firmware-b43-installer`). the output in the answer now

Comment: I don't see any changes in the question And I do not see any trace of `bcmwl-kernel-source` installed. Please post output of `sudo modprobe wl`. Maybe you didn't notice the change in the output.

Comment: Now it looks great. It should be working now. Uncommenting anything in conf was wrong. Check `rfkill list` if it's not, or try to reboot.

Comment: You have the correct `wl` driver in use now. You could have installed it from the very beginning.

Comment: Maybe you removed Network-Manger etc. It is not a driver issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with an Xubuntu clean install the answer to using the broadcom wifi was to

1. use bcmwl-kernel-source and
2. start the kernel with intremap=off

The bcmwl-kernel-source can be installed as pilot6 mentioned, or (in Xubuntu) via software & updates -> add drivers -> using proprietary, which also will mention the bcmwl-kernel-source.

The kernel switch answer is found in the thread below in post #10: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2405673. Other switches that worked were pci=noacpi, or acpi=off, or acpi=noirq.

thanks for the help received for this question